# why toString does not work properly on data.frame created manually?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data.frame that is manually created like:

```
a = data.frame(a = c(1,3,4), b = c(1,3,4))
> a
  a b
1 1 1
2 3 3
3 4 4
```

I want to convert the elements in the data.frame to string,
but I got this:

```
> toString(a)
[1] "c(1, 3, 4), c(1, 3, 4)"
```

anyone helps?

a similar question has been asked and answered, so we probably can change the question to why toString does not work properly on data.frame?

And the accepted answer gives some clue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to do this on each column, loop over the columns with `sapply/lapply` and apply the `toString`

```
sapply(a, toString)
```

If the OP wanted to convert the columns to `character` class we can use `lapply` in `base R`

```
a[] <- lapply(a, as.character)
```

---

`toString` is `paste(..., collapse=", ")` and `paste` converts its arguments via `as.character` to character strings, but `as.character` calls `as.vector` and it is calling on the `data.frame` directly and which cause this issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation! lapply solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `across` function from `dplyr` package, to apply a function in every column of your data.frame. In your case, you can convert all of your data to characters using the `as.character()` function.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- mutate(a, across(.fns = as.character))

str(a)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr  "1" "3" "4"
 $ b: chr  "1" "3" "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

library(dplyr)

```
a %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     1    
2 3     3    
3 4     4
```

Or is this?

```
a %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), toString)) %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  a       b      
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 1, 3, 4 1, 3, 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! the above one is what I want.